# LYX fail to start

Tags: errors, lyx

I'm using miKTeK 2.9 and installed both winedt and LYX 2.1. They worked well before yesterday.
I have just install Lyx version 2.3.3 but when I open LYX the window reported that "This application fail to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin Window" in "". Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
I have install LYX so many times but this error repeats again and again.
Note, winedt has still work well
Please, help me to solve this
thank you so much

Comment: Add a bug report to the lyx bug tracker.

Comment: Where did you get the installer? Do you mean LyX 2.2.3? LyX 2.3.3 does not exist yet.

Comment: I have reinstall mikTeK and now LyX work well. The reason of this error comes from updating MikTeK. Thank you for all your attensions.